# Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3 Console: Not enough memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just upgraded to Rails 3, and in the last 24 hours I have started to see a new error message popping up in my console:

```
Errno::ENOMEM: Not enough space - <STDOUT>
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `write'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `printf'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'Maybe IRB bug!!
```

This is a particularly annoying error because I cannot carry out any Rails operations concerning more than ~50 records. How can this be fixed?